# iOS: How do I rename a folder in the documents directory

Tags: ios, filesystems

I'm not sure if this is a silly question. If I move a file using `-[NSFileManger moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:]` from one place e.g. `/Images/image.png` to say `/OtherImages/image.png` will the old directory `/Images` be deleted automatically or will it still exist? Also, if I wanted to rename Images to Pictures could this be done in iOS or do I just have to move everything to a new path/url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you move a file using `[NSFileManager moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:]` the source directory won't be deleted. If it was the only file, it will stay empty.

To rename a directory, you use the same command, just don't specify any files. For example:

```
NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init];
[NSFileManager moveItemAtPath:@"/Images/" toPath:@"/OtherImages/" error:&error];
```

and the directory will be renamed to OtherImages and it will also keep all its contents.

Comment: The moveItemAtPath:toPath:error: method is actually an instance method, so you'll need to do something like [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:source toPath:destination error:&error].

Comment: And NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init];  is must be NSError* error;